# Need explanation of why one transfer instruction works but the other doesn't

Tags: anchor-lang, transfer

I have a simple account like so.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateItem<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = creator,
        space = ITEM_SIZE,
        seeds = [ITEM_SEED],
        bump
    )]
    pub item: Account<'info,Item>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub to_pda: Account<'info, OtherPda>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info,System>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
#[account]
pub struct Item {
    pub creator: Pubkey,
    pub deposit: u64
}
```

`OtherPda` already created and is fine.
If I transfer funds this way it works.

```
pub fn new_item(ctx: Context<CreateItem>,deposit: u16) -> Result<()> { 
   let item: &mut Account<Item> = &mut ctx.accounts.item;
   let creator: &AccountInfo = &ctx.accounts.creator;

   //Set variables
   item.creator = creator.key();
   item.deposit = deposit as u64 * 1000000000;

   let deposit_lamports = deposit as u64 * 1000000000;
   let from_account = &ctx.accounts.creator;
   let to_account = &ctx.accounts.to_pda;

        // Create the transfer instruction
        let transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(from_account.key, 
        to_account.to_account_info().key, deposit_lamports);

        // Invoke the transfer instruction
        anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
            &transfer_instruction,
            &[
                from_account.to_account_info(),
                to_account.to_account_info().clone(),
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ],
            &[],
        )?;
   
   Ok(())
}
/// This works fine. Funds get transferred and PDA account created.
```

But if I do it this way I get an error
"instruction spent from the balance of an account it does not own"

```
pub fn new_item(ctx: Context<CreateItem>,deposit: u16) -> Result<()> { 
   let item: &mut Account<Item> = &mut ctx.accounts.item;
   let creator: &AccountInfo = &ctx.accounts.creator;

   //Set variables
   item.creator = creator.key();
   item.deposit = deposit as u64 * 1000000000;

   let deposit_lamports = deposit as u64 * 1000000000;
   let creator_lamports = ctx.accounts.creator.lamports();
   let to_pda_lamports = ctx.accounts.universe.to_account_info().lamports();
        

    **ctx.accounts.to_pda.to_account_info().lamports.borrow_mut() = to_pda_lamports.checked_add(deposit_lamports).unwrap();

    **ctx.accounts.creator.lamports.borrow_mut() = creator_lamports.checked_sub(deposit_lamports).unwrap();
   
   Ok(())
}
///I GET ERROR: instruction spent from the balance of an account it does not own
```

I looked up the error and found

```
/// Program spent the lamports of an account that doesn't belong to it
#[error("instruction spent from the balance of an account it does not own")]
ExternalAccountLamportSpend
```

Can anyone explain why one transfer works and the other one doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the account you are subsctracting from is not a PDA it will most likely be owned by the system program so you need to use a CPI for that like so:

```
 let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            system_program::Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info().clone(),
                to: ctx.accounts.chest_vault.to_account_info().clone(),
            },
        );
        system_program::transfer(cpi_context, CHEST_REWARD)?;
```

Here is a playground example showing both cases.
https://beta.solpg.io/tutorials/tiny-adventure-two

Your progam is only allowed to change the lamports of an account it is the owner of. If the owner is the system program only the system program can change it so you need to use a CPI.

Comment: This cleared things up. Thank you! Is there any difference between making the transaction your way with ```CpiContext::new``` and the way it worked for me ```anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed```?

Comment: No thats just another way of writing it. Pick whatever you like better.